# Astral projection question

Tags: yoga, tantra, chakras

Where is method to astral projection (sookshma sharira,) described, is there any mudra/Asana to help simulate astral projection, mentioned?

Comment: Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms.There is no mudra or asana for it. It is not a 'mechanical' physical system. What is required is a deep concentration of the mind, a certain level of consciousness.

Comment: Astral projection is of Aatma out of body, but the question is why you want to project soul out of body? Difference between a dead and an alive person is that an alive person has soul but dead does not.

Comment: To explore the universe